# How to compile in Objective-C with XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a finished program that I wrote with Objective-C in XCode 3.2.3. I would like to compile it into a format that I can import into iTunes. Under the Build menu, there is an option that says Compile, but it is grayed out and won't let me select that. How can I compile it into iTunes format (I believe the format is .ipa)?

Comment: None of your solutions worked but thank you for your time anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://idotcomllc.wordpress.com/2009/05/26/how-to-build-a-ipa-file-from-xcode/